# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Boot is in Infinite Loop

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. This is NOT a dual-boot system, and it has been running fine for months.
This morning, when I turned on the machine, it displayed the Ubuntu graphic, then displayed the following lines of text:

[0.234222] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
/dev/sdb1: clean, 778818/61054976 files, 70963067/24419028 blocks

So far, this is all normal. However, the boot process stopped here. Every 10 or 20 seconds, the screen would clear for an instant, and the same two lines of text would be displayed. This behavior continued (as far as I know) indefinitely.

I installed boot-repair and tried the recommended repair option. The link to the pastebin from this repair is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WDxjGBY6Nq/  This did not fix the issue.

Next, I ran boot-repair and requested a bootinfo summary. That summary is located here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Fh9RS2JwPk/

I have no clue where to proceed from here. Any advice would be welcome.

---- Added on 19-jun-2023 ----
Thx for the tips. I can boot into recovery mode. Here is the output from the journalctl command:
(all lines of output are prefixed by "Jun 19 07:43:57 RJW-HPE-150t")
kernel: x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
/etc/udev/rules.d/55-brother-broscan4-linsane-type1.rules:9 Invalid key 'SYSFS'
/etc/udev/rules.d/55-brother-libsane-type1-inst.rules:14 Invalid key 'SYSFS'
/etc/udev/rules.d/55-epson-libsane.rules:1 Invalid operator for MODE.
/etc/udev/rules.d/55-epson-libsane.ruels:2 invalid operator for MODE.
avahi-daemon[915]: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
---- end of journalctl output ----

I ran fsck from the GRUB menu. Here is the output:
lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
/dev/sdb1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting

This did not fix my problem.

Someone mentioned a dedicated graphics board. I did install a new NVIDIA board on 18-Apr-2023 and have had no issues (in fact, before I installed the board, I was experiencing random system freezes, mostly on websites with video content - those freezes stopped completely with the new board.)

I have not made any changes to my system; however, it is possible that an update ran in the background.

I tried the dpkg command. After many lines of scrolling text, I got the following report:

2 packages are going to be removed. 8 new packages are going to be installed. 13 packages are going to be upgraded.
You have to download a total of 299 M. This download will take about 59 seconds with a 40Mbit connection and about 7 minutes with a 5Mbit connection.

I pressed y to continue. After many mode scrolled lines of text, I got the following:

Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Restoring original system state
Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Finished, please press ENTER

I suspect that dpkg could not connect to the Internet. I enabled networking and repeated the dpkg. This time, I could see some download activity, and the process appeared to complete normally.

...and my machine is BACK. Rocket, you /rock/. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please boot to recovery mode and [edit] your question to add the output of `journalctl --boot=0 --priority=3 --no-pager`  … Does your machine have a dedicated graphics card e.g. NVIDIA? … I haven’t had a look at your boot repair log as it requires a login to view, but your system appears to be able to boot and that is not the problem.